# unpivot or melt a given data frame to the desired output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, unpivot

the data which I have look like

```
Name   Number
A1      12,13,14,15
A2       8,9,10
A3       5,6,7
A4       3,5,7
```

output should come in the format

```
Name     Number
A1        12
A1        13
A1        14
A1        15
A2         8
.          .
.
.          .
```

tried unpivot, tried stack() after splitting data. not able to get to desired output

Comment: `df.assign(Number=df['Number'].str.split(',')).explode('Number')`.

Comment: Thank you soo much. got the expected result